# How can I edit content of register WITH mode change keys?

Tags: vim

When I record operations with registers of vim, I found there's a control character in register content(for example the register 'q'):

```
o^[iabc^[
```

Of course, when I '@q' in vim, I can open a new line, insert 'abc', and return to normal mode.
But if I want to replace 'abc' to 'def' or add 'def' after 'abc', how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are saved in registers and you can yank into and put from a register:

```
"qp
(edit the line)
"qy$
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pasting and cutting as per romainl's answer (which requires some scratch space in a buffer), you can often also directly edit in the command line:

```
:let @q = <C-r><C-r>=string(@q)<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

this line works for your need too:

```
:let @q=substitute(@q, 'abc', 'abcdef','')
```